# How can set DirectoryIndex only for one directory in apache?

Tags: apache2, directoryindex

I tried this:

```
<Directory path>
DirectoryIndex a/b
</Directory>
```

But in this way, the DirectoryIndex rule will be aplied all of the subdirectories of path. I want it to work only in the top level.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Apache version 2.3.9 or greater, you can use DirectoryMatch with the end-of-line match ("$").

```
<DirectoryMatch "^/var/www/html/path/$" >
    DirectoryIndex a/b
</DirectoryMatch>
```

Comment: I'm using version 2.4.38, but it doesn't work to me.

Comment: I've tested it with that version.  Perhaps you have more in your Apache configuration.   BTW, what is "a/b" ???

Comment: It works for me if I remove $ from the beginning. "b" is a file under "a" folder.

Comment: OMG, I'm so sorry!   The first "$" has to be a "^" !!